# Hiding row if there is data in all cells of a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've searched high and low but couldn't find an answer to fit my issue. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out a code for..

If all cells in a row contain data then hide the row; if there is a blank cell within the row, don't hide it. Repeat for entire named range.

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to change if something is hidden / unhidden is with VBA

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub hideFullRow()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim hide As Boolean

hide = True

Set rng = Range("Name")
For Each rw In rng.Rows
    For Each c In rw.Cells
        If IsEmpty(c) Then 
            hide = False
            exit For
        End If
    Next
    rw.EntireRow.Hidden = hide
Next

End Sub
```